# Was there any attempt to have Q meet Archer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I've seen Enterprise many times, and it only now occurred to me that Archer never encountered Q or a member of the Q Continuum.

If you believe [Trelane](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trelane) is part of the Q Continuum, then it would seem every captain until Sisko encountered Q or a member of the Q Continuum. As I remember, I don't think Archer ever encountered super-powerful, near-omnipotent aliens.

Other than Vulcans and Klingons, did the writers want to avoid aliens we've previously seen to bring in new viewers?

Comment: Archer met the Organians.

Comment: @Valorum - You're right, didn't realize that!

Comment: Since Picard's encounter was supposed to the first one with a Q, it makes sense that there was nothing before that.

Comment: @JackBNimble But there is always the "previous encounters were kept secret" gambit to explain that in prequels. (Especially the "previous encounters were suppressed by the time police" gambit).

Comment: Given that the Q can assume human form, there's no way to say for certain that Archer has never met any of the Q

Comment: Archer's "Q" character was Daniels from the 30th century (for all intents and purposes).

Comment: As seen in Voyager s2ep18 ["Death Wish"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)), members of the Q Continuum (Quinn, in particular) have interacted with humanity long long long before TNG. So Archer certainly could have met a Q and not known it.